# Google support for enterprise Android development

Tags: android, enterprise

Does Google offer any support program for enterprise Android development?

Something similar to Apple's [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)?

A search on Internet didn't yield any results, so I'm wondering if anyone here know of such an existing/future program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS developer Enterprise Program:

> 1)    Distribute Your In-house Apps
>
> 2)    Test on iPad, iPhone, and iPod touch
>
> 3)    Receive Code Level Technical Support
>
> 4)    Get Your Questions Answered in the Apple Developer Forums

1) Android allow to do that, you can choose to allow unsigned app or signed, no matter, simply put you file in a web and allow to the client to download and install it.

2) android allow to do that to test directly in the target machine.

3) meh

4) meh x 2

As a enterprise level, the main problem of Android is the lack of proxy support.   Right now, everyone can do a Android program for free and distribute it amongst the corporate users.   It is pretty easy to do that without any hack.

Instead, in iOS, you must have a Apple certificate since you must sign every application, plus the fact that you signed application can run only in a specific machine, i.e. you can't copy and pass it freely.

Comment: The problem is pushing updates when you just have it sitting on a web server. Email blasts are a little unprofessional. They need to offer additional repositories or options like that in the market.

Comment: Yes, update is a problem.  But, the program can check automatically and refuse to install (and redirect to the page) if there are a new version of the program.  It is easy to do that.

Comment: hi magallanes.. the android users have to select the install from unknown sources option in settings to install apks..right is there any turnaround

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://www.push-link.com/ . They offer the service you are looking for.

Comment: Did you notice the typo on the website? ...lol  "Get notieced when apps..."

Answer (score 0):

I have recently discussed various Enterprise Mobility functions and Android support for them. You can find the details [here](http://techtej.blogspot.com/2011/06/enterprise-mobility-and-android.html).

Answer (score 0):

Visit this link to learn about Google's support for Android enterprise application development:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html