# What are requirements for an organization to submit an enterprise app in Android Market and BlackBerry market

Tags: android, blackberry, enterprise

For an enterprise application, what are requirements for an organisation. Like we have to pay for publishing our application in android market, similarly is there, we need to pay for enterprise application? Any other rules for an organisation.

A search on Internet didn't yield any results. I followed some articles like [support for enterprise app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807256/google-support-for-enterprise-android-development)  , [Android enterprise](http://www.techworld.com.au/article/313742/android_enterprise_fast/) , and [Blackberry enterprise development](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/started/enterprise.jsp).

Thanx.

Comment: This is offtopic, because it is a question about RIM and Google policy, not programming.

Comment: So can you explain where should I put this question? Is http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ is right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey i see what you are asking...

1)there is no such thing like enterprise applications in android market. All the applications are same.

2) there is no additional cost or so....i just publish your app in a standard way.

3) If your looking for a app catalog for your enterprise look at this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997202/android-enterprise-market/6739757#6739757

4) Device Administration API's and a Online Enterprise App catalog(where you list all your apps) can be done to secure,manage your enterprise devices which use your enterprise apps.

Answer (score 1):

great question. No requirements persay on submitting apps from Google but more so from your own company concerning security/privacy.  Check out this podcast I did with Greg Hansen from Motorola Mobility discusses how they use the Android Market to distribute apps to Motorola employees.

Visit http://developer.motorola.com/eventstraining/podcasts/appdistributiondec13/

Answer (score 0):

for the android market you need to register an account and just publish your app. google doens't really have any restrictions like apple has for the iphone apps. its quite simple and straightforward. you just need to pay 25$ for creating the market account through google checkout.

And what exactly do you mean by publishing an enterprise app? how is that different from a normal android app? There really isn't a different way of deploying the apps on the market. its just the standard normal way of building, signing and uploading the app. The app code in a regular app isn't with a different structure than an enterprise app (apps build with the help of the android sdk, tested on android devices written with the help of the same classes and ment to be deployed on the same phones as any other app out there)...

Comment: i didn't downvote. but someone else did... your question isn't really clear. you need to try express yourself a bit better. after all we are here trying to help you.

Comment: I know about android market and and its registration process. Actually I am asking about Enterprise application registration.